# something wrong with my API call, using Retrofit with moshi converter

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, viewmodel, moshi

I am learning Android development and I am trying to build a simple news app.
but I have been stuck for 3 days not able to fetch the json response from the server.
I think something wrong with my retrofit call but I can't figure what it is. I check the logcat and there is no response printed !
I appreciate any help. (I changed my API key because it is personal)

```
private const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface CallNewsApi {
    @GET("/v2/top-headlines")
    suspend fun getHeadlines(
        @Query("apiKey") key: String,
        @Query("category") category: String,
        @Query("country") country: String
    ): Response<NewsApiResponse>
}

object NewsApi {
    val retrofitService: CallNewsApi by lazy {
        retrofit.create(CallNewsApi::class.java)
    }
}

data class NewsApiResponse(
    var status: String,
    var totalResults: Int,
    var articles: List<NewsHeadlines>
)

data class NewsHeadlines(
    var source: Source,
    var author: String,
    var title: String,
    var description: String,
    var url: String,
    var urlToImage: String,
    var publishedAt: String,
    var content: String
)

data class Source(
    var id: String,
    var name: String
)

class NewsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _newsList = MutableLiveData<List<NewsHeadlines>>()
    val status: LiveData<List<NewsHeadlines>> = _newsList
    init {
        getNewsLines()
    }
    private fun getNewsLines() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                Log.d("ViewModel"," before retrofit")
                val call = NewsApi.retrofitService.getHeadlines(
                    "myApiKey",
                    "sports",
                    "il"
                )
                Log.d("ViewModel", call.body().toString())
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                _newsList.value = listOf()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `Response<NewsApiResponse>` with just `NewsApiResponse`. Also, what error are you getting? Do you see the `before retrofit` log printed in logcat? What about the log after the request?

Comment: Hi Arpit, I have replaced with only NewsApiResponse without any success, i get this message in the Run  tab 'W/System: A resource failed to call close.' Log after request dosn't return anything, seems like the app dosn't return from the call at all

Comment: Add a `Log.e("TAG", "message", e)` in the catch block to see what error are you getting in the logcat

Comment: E  message
                                                                                                    com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Non-null value 'id' was null at $.articles[0].source.id
                                                                                                     at com.squareup.moshi.internal.Util.unexpectedNull(Util.java:674)

Comment: You do not have the id field in your json response. Can you add the json response sent by the api in the question? You can use Postman (or any other tool) to get the api response.

Comment: Hi Arpit,thank you very much for your hints! here is a link of the json response that I suppose to get  "https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines" , it apears that some fields are null, but in my kotlin data classes these attributes were nun nullable. I added a ? sign to the id , author and content , and now I am getting a retrofit call printed in the logcat , seems that I have succeded, but I am not sure if I should make all my data class fields and nested object nullable or not ?

Comment: Make sure to use the Kotlin support for Moshi https://github.com/square/moshi#codegen

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sample responses in the API [documentation](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines), it seems that a lot of the fields in the json response can be `null` like `source.id`, `author`, `content`, `description` and  `urlToImage`. For these fields you should use nullable properties i.e. `String?`.

Since the documentation doesn't explicitly mention which fields can be null and which can't be, it's upto you whether you want to mark all of them as nullable or not. But you can skip those which you think will always be present. For example, I think that `status`, `totalResults`, `publishedAt`, `title`, `source.name` should always be present in the news response, so you can choose to keep these as non-nullable.